# insert data from gridview through for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I was getting the following error for inserting data from datatable . The displayed error is    The variable name '@ndate1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. am new for .net . HOw can i fix this error please help me to fix this error..

My parital code is here..

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= DT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dr["company"]);
                sqlcmd.CommandText = @" Insert into tbl_rtdata (fld_date,fld_dtcode,fld_company,fld_primary,fld_sales,fld_balance)
               values (@ndate1,@dtcode1,@company1,@billing1,@sales1,@balance1)";
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ndate1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["ndate"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtcode1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["dtcode"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["company"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billing1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["billing"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["sales"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["balance"]);


                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

First Row only inserted into database...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(); 
            sqlcmd.Connection = objconn;

            //sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(dr["company"]);
            sqlcmd.CommandText = @" Insert into tbl_rtdata (fld_date,fld_dtcode,fld_company,fld_primary,fld_sales,fld_balance)
           values (@ndate1,@dtcode1,@company1,@billing1,@sales1,@balance1)";
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ndate1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["ndate"]);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtcode1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["dtcode"]);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["company"]);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billing1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["billing"]);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["sales"]);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["balance"]);


            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Hope this will help you....happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear` else it will maintain the parameter collection from the first loop.

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= DT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
                sqlcmd.CommandText = @" Insert into tbl_rtdata (fld_date,fld_dtcode,fld_company,fld_primary,fld_sales,fld_balance)
               values (@ndate1,@dtcode1,@company1,@billing1,@sales1,@balance1)";
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ndate1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["ndate"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtcode1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["dtcode"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["company"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billing1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["billing"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["sales"]);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(DT.Rows[i]["balance"]);


                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```